# Some questions about prototype and array

Tags: javascript

I found the codes on the book, and had some problems with it.

```
var elems = {};
Array.prototype.push.call(elems, document.getElementById("first"));
alert(elems[0].nodeType);  /It would output 1
```

1. I know the "call" is to bind the push method to "elems" object. But the "elems" is an empty
   object, why does the empty object has the "push" method?
2. I tried to discard the "prototype" from  Array.prototype.push to  Array.push. But it did not 
   work. Why? As I know from the book that the method would be found due to the prototype    chain.
   Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `var elems = [];`?

Comment: No, then they could just do `elems.push`.  This code seems to be demonstrating the ability to call an `Array` method on a non-`Array` object.

Comment: Just because you can do that, doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: @Andy: There are many uses to apply the behavior of `Array.prototype` methods to non Array objects. The specification explicitly states that they are to be generic and therefore able to operate on non-Arrays.

Comment: @cookiemonster, the only two I can think of are converting non-array lists (arguments and nodelists) to proper arrays. I can't think of an example when I'd need to use `Array.prototype` on an object. Perhaps I've just not come across an example in my own work.

Comment: @Andy: Do you use jQuery?

Comment: @Andy: That's a prime example. jQuery objects are just regular objects, but they have a `.length` and numeric indices like Arrays. Internally they use `Array.prototype` methods to perform operations on the jQuery objects.

Comment: Funny :) I always thought it was the other way round. Arrays with methods attached. Anyway, many thanks for replying. Nice discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample console session to clear things up (read the comments):

```
var elems = {};
Array.prototype.push.call(elems, 10); // you're telling 'push' to act like the argument is an array, even if it's not
// that's what 'call' does
> 1 // note that 'push' returns the length of the resultant array
elems
> Object {0: 10, length: 1} // 'push' is *acting* like 'elems' is an array, when really it's not
> Array.prototype.push // getting from 'prototype' which is basically all the properties that every Array has
function push() { [native code] }
> Array.push // this doesn't exist
undefined
> [].push // shows the 'prototype' chain
function push() { [native code] }
```

Comment: @user2837851 Because `[]` doesn't *have* a `prototype` property. It's an instance of `Array`.

Answer (score 2):

Your object doesn't have the push method. By using `.call()`, you're instructing `.push()` to operate on the object as though it was an array, which does work.

The `Array.push` doesn't work (except in Firefox) because `.push` is a method inherited for all Array objects. As such, it exists on the `.prototype` of the `Array` constructor.

---

If you did this:

```
[].push.call(elems, ...)
```

it would work because you're creating a new Array, and getting `.push()` via inheritance, which comes from `Array.prototype`.

---

In Firefox, you'd just need to do this:

```
Array.push(elems, document.getElementById("first"));
```

This is because Firefox has what it calls "Array generics", which accept the object on which to operate as the first argument, and the item to push as the second (or more).